# Access result of Ansible task in 'changed_when' and 'failed_when'

Tags: ansible

I have a task, which looks like this MWE:

```yaml
- name: Remove {{ atlassiandb }} database
  shell:
    cmd: "export VALUE='ABC' && echo $VALUE"
  register: shell_result
  become: yes
  failed_when: "'ERROR' in shell_result.stderr"
  changed_when: "'abc' in shell_result.stdout"
```

When I run it, I get the error `'dict object' has no attribute 'sterr'`. But if I force run the task with `failed_when: false` and print `shell_result` with the `debug` module, it does have this attribute.

According to different sources, this seems to be the right approach, but it looks like the values are not accessible, until the task is completed, hence `changed_when` is passed. I could duplicate it and run the first one with `check_mode: yes` and use the result from the check-run, but this is bad code.

Is there any nice way, or is it simply not possible?

Comment: This should work. Looking at your error, are you sure you did not do a typo: `'dict object' has no attribute 'sterr'`, is true, the attribute is `stderr` not `sterr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce your error. Your given example task result into an output of

```yaml
ok: [localhost] =>
  shell_result:
    changed: false
    cmd: export VALUE='ABC' && echo $VALUE
    delta: '0:00:00.009706'
    end: '2022-07-14 18:30:00.515899'
    failed: false
    failed_when_result: false
    rc: 0
    start: '2022-07-14 18:30:00.506193'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: ABC
    stdout_lines:
    - ABC
```

or in check mode

```yaml
ok: [localhost] =>
  shell_result:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    msg: skipped, running in check mode
    skipped: true
```

Depending on what you try to achieve, you may have a look into the documentation

- [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditions-based-on-registered-variables)
- [`shell` module - Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-values)
- [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure)

and could use also something like

```yaml
failed_when: shell_result.rc != 0
```

---

Please take note that after your example task finish, the shell environment will disappear and for the next task there will be no `VALUE` anymore. Therefore it might be that

```yaml
changed_when: "'abc' in shell_result.stdout"
```

will never become `true`.

See [Setting the remote environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html).

Comment: This was meant to be a simplified example. I know, that it can't become true. But at least I know, that I'm doing it right. In theory.